# Problems with generated mesh/model using normals and texture, libgdx 3d api

Tags: opengl, 3d, libgdx, rendering, mesh

I have been stuck for some time figuring out why I fail at generating a textured mesh with normals from a heightmap image. I am using the TerrainTest (http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/TerrainTest.java) code and have only added code for generating normals and tex coords:

```
private void calcNormals(short[] indices, float[] verts) {

      Vector3 point1=new Vector3(), point2=new Vector3(), point3=new Vector3();

       for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i += 3) {
           int i1 = getPositionStart(indices[i + 0]);
           int i2 = getPositionStart(indices[i + 1]);
           int i3 = getPositionStart(indices[i + 2]);

           point1.set(verts[i1 + 0], verts[i1 + 1], verts[i1 + 2]);
           point2.set(verts[i2 + 0], verts[i2 + 1], verts[i2 + 2]);
           point3.set(verts[i3 + 0], verts[i3 + 1], verts[i3 + 2]);

           Vector3 v1 = new Vector3().set(point2).sub(point1);
            Vector3 v2 = new Vector3().set(point3).sub(point1);
            Vector3 nor = v1.crs(v2).nor();

           addNormal(indices[i + 0], verts, nor.x, nor.y, nor.z);
           addNormal(indices[i + 1], verts, nor.x, nor.y, nor.z);
           addNormal(indices[i + 2], verts, nor.x, nor.y, nor.z);
       }

   }
```

Texture coordinates I add in the modified buildVertices() method:

```
public void buildVertices() {
    int heightPitch = height + 1;
    int widthPitch = width + 1;

    int idx = 0;
    int hIdx = 0;

    Gdx.app.log("DBG","height map size="+heightMap.length);
    for (int z = 0; z < heightPitch; z++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < widthPitch; x++) {

            // POSITION
            vertices[idx++] = x;
            vertices[idx++] = heightMap[hIdx++] * strength;
            vertices[idx++] = z;

            // NORMAL, skip these for now
            idx += 3;

            // COLOR
            vertices[idx++] = Color.WHITE.toFloatBits();

            // TEXTURE
            vertices[idx++] = (x / (float) width);
            vertices[idx++] = (z / (float) height);

        }
    }
}
```

This is the only code I have changed in the TerrainTest.TerrainChunk class.

I then create a mesh:

```
 int vertexSize = 3 + 3 + 1 + 2;
  TerrainChunk chunk = new TerrainChunk(4, 4, vertexSize, "textures/heightmap.png", 10);
            groundMesh = new Mesh(true, chunk.vertices.length / 3, chunk.indices.length, 
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE), 
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.Normal, 3, ShaderProgram.NORMAL_ATTRIBUTE),
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked, 4, ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE), 
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2,  ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE));

  groundMesh.setVertices(chunk.vertices);
  groundMesh.setIndices(chunk.indices);
```

After that I only create a btBvhTriangleMeshShape and a Model from the Mesh:

```
Material material = new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE), ColorAttribute.createSpecular(Color.WHITE),
        FloatAttribute.createShininess(16f));

  Model result = new Model();

  int chunkNum = 0;
  MeshPart meshPart = new MeshPart();
  meshPart.id = "terrainChunk" + chunkNum;
  meshPart.indexOffset = 0;
  meshPart.numVertices = groundMesh.getNumIndices();
  meshPart.primitiveType = GL20.GL_TRIANGLES;
  meshPart.mesh = groundMesh;

  btTriangleIndexVertexArray bttiva = new btTriangleIndexVertexArray(meshPart);
  btBvhTriangleMeshShape heightFieldShape = new btBvhTriangleMeshShape(bttiva, true);

  NodePart nodePart = new NodePart();
  nodePart.material = material;
  nodePart.meshPart = meshPart;

  Node node = new Node();
  node.id = "terrainNode" + chunkNum;
  node.parts.add(nodePart);

  result.meshes.add(groundMesh);
  result.materials.add(material);
  result.nodes.add(node);
  result.meshParts.add(meshPart);
  result.manageDisposable(groundMesh);
```

I render the Mesh and btShape with DebugDrawModes.DBG_DrawNormals | DebugDrawModes.DBG_DrawWireframe So I can see the wire and normals of the btShape.

No matter what I do the mesh and rigidBody's normals is pointing downward (-y) and the mesh's texture is drawn in uniform color (like the average color of the texture) on its bottom side. The strange thing is that no matter if I change the normals calculation (i.e using -normal.y instead of +normal.y) the debugdraw's normals wont change! and the mesh can only bee seen from below. I have printed all data in the groundMesh.getVertices() and everything seems right to me. Below is the 9 components printed for each vertex (2x2 TerrainChunk for testing):

```
DBG: Vertex: 0.0,9.803922,0.0,0.07673953,0.9784201,0.19184695,-1.7014117E38,0.0,0.0
DBG: Vertex: 1.0,9.725491,0.0,0.15213917,0.96989024,0.19017535,-1.7014117E38,0.5,0.0
DBG: Vertex: 2.0,9.6470585,0.0,0.07541871,0.96157986,0.26396275,-1.7014117E38,1.0,0.0
DBG: Vertex: 0.0,9.607843,1.0,0.11272618,0.9581794,0.2630302,-1.7014117E38,0.0,0.5
DBG: Vertex: 1.0,9.529411,1.0,0.21905276,0.93097335,0.29206917,-1.7014117E38,0.5,0.5
DBG: Vertex: 2.0,9.372549,1.0,0.14450188,0.9212023,0.36125556,-1.7014117E38,1.0,0.5
DBG: Vertex: 0.0,9.333333,2.0,0.11272618,0.9581794,0.2630302,-1.7014117E38,0.0,1.0
DBG: Vertex: 1.0,9.215687,2.0,0.21905276,0.93097335,0.29206917,-1.7014117E38,0.5,1.0
DBG: Vertex: 2.0,8.980392,2.0,0.21905276,0.93097335,0.29206917,-1.7014117E38,1.0,1.0
```

The normals (index 3,4 and 5) are all pointing up! But the debugdraw has normals pointing down and the mesh is only visible from below.

If I change the way normals is calculated so it yields some other values I can see this confirmed when I print the vertex's content but the debugdraw and mesh stays the same.. how is this even possible, it is like the mesh totally ignores the normal values.

Answer (score 3):

## The problem

This seems to be a problem somewhere down the renderpipeline. The normals for back-face culling don't seem to be determined by the normals provided, but by the winding of the triangles (caused by the vertex order).

### Workaround

A **workaround** to this is, to change the order you provide the indices when building your mesh.

So for example in the LibGDX TerrainTest (which you based your code on) where the indices are created in the *buildIndices* method:

```
indices[idx++] = i1;
indices[idx++] = i2;
indices[idx++] = i3;

indices[idx++] = i3;
indices[idx++] = i4;
indices[idx++] = i1;
```

Change the order of the last two indices for every triangle like so:

```
indices[idx++] = i1;
indices[idx++] = i3; //i3 is exchanged
indices[idx++] = i2; //with i2

indices[idx++] = i3;
indices[idx++] = i1; //i1 is exchanged
indices[idx++] = i4; //with i4
```

This will change the 'winding' of the triangle and it should now render for you correctly.

### Solution

The **solution** would be to file a bug in the LibGDX bugtracker so that they get it fixed, because I do not think this is expected behaviour.

(PS: I hope this isn't too late, but since this caused me a lot of headache, I figured maybe it could help some people.)